# How to a set a variable for a rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Hello I want to set the following:

```
AssetHash::Base.asset_paths = ['assets']
```

as seen here: https://github.com/donaldpiret/asset_hash

I added it to an initializer, to environment.rb but it never takes effect. Here's the actually gem source for this: https://github.com/donaldpiret/asset_hash/blob/master/lib/asset_hash.rb

Can you please help me understand where I can set this config option?

Thanks

Comment: I would add it to an initializer. I hope you did not forget to restart your rails process after adding it to the initializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is good, weird it doesn't work.

Another one is to override the `self.asset_paths` method since it is supposed to provide the proper paths.

In an initializer:

```
 AssetHash::Base.class_eval do
   def self.assets_path
      your_array_here
   end
 end
```

---